# Windows 10 Search & Indexing Not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, search-indexing

My search index on windows 10 does not work currently.

I have tried to go into the indexing settings but every time i go into indexing options it gets stuck on "Waiting to receive indexing status" [Screenshot of Indexing Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkdKZ.png) if i click on Advanced, the program freezes and will not go away till i restart.
I have tried erasing the index from different methods and tried restarting the service but to no solution.

My searches work from the start menu but if i try from windows explorer it freezes and won't do anything.

Comment: Try to restart `windows search` service to see if helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Windows 10. I have discovered a work around.(By the way, you don't need to "Restart" to get rid of "Indexing Options" box -just run "Task Manager" by right clicking the task bar at the bottom of screen - select Task Manager- do "end Task" on "Windows host process Rundll32)

Now for the work around!

- On your keyboard Click - the Windows key and S
- a black box appears
- at the bottom where it says "Type here to search" enter what you are looking for.
- Hey Presto... results.

Note: on the top of the black box you may need to select the icon for local
   search.

I also have a problem with searching in Outlook365 and my work around for that is to start Outlook in safe mode. Go Window key (on keyboard) plus R - the type outlook.exe /safe. outlook opens and you can search.